# searchbar, button and sliding options in ionic2 not working

Tags: javascript, html, angular, ionic2

```
<ion-header>
    <ion-navbar>
        <button ion-button menuToggle>
            <ion-icon name="menu"></ion-icon>
        </button>
        <ion-title>Home</ion-title>
    </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content padding>
    <ion-searchbar (ionInput)="getItems($event)"></ion-searchbar>
    <ion-list>
        <ion-item-sliding *ngFor="let detail of details">
            <ion-item>
                <h2>{{detail.Fname}} {{detail.Lname}}</h2>
            </ion-item>

            <ion-item-options side="left" icon-left>
                <button ion-button color="primary" (click)="buttonClick(detail)">
                    <ion-icon name="clipboard"></ion-icon>
                    Edit
                </button>
                <button ion-button color="danger" (click)="deleteEmpDetail(detail)">
                    <ion-icon name="trash"></ion-icon>
                    Delete
                </button>
            </ion-item-options>
        </ion-item-sliding>
    </ion-list>

    <ion-tabs color="light">
        <ion-fab right bottom (click)="addEmployee()">
            <button ion-fab mini color="dark">
                <ion-icon name="add"></ion-icon>
            </button>
        </ion-fab>
    </ion-tabs>
</ion-content>
```

I am trying to create an app using Ionic2. This is my home.html page which shows the list of employees. I've added a sliding option to each item that has options to delete and edit. I've also added a search-bar option. But none of it seems to be not working. Please help.

Comment: what is the exact error you're getting?

Comment: I'm not getting any error. The app loads correctly but the sliding option and other things are not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below code shows correct way to implement search bar and sliding option in list using ionic2.

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar color="primary" no-border-bottom>
    <ion-buttons start>
      <button ion-button class="navBtnRight" (click)="dismiss()">
        <span color="light" showWhen="ios">Cancel</span>
        <ion-icon color="light" name="md-close" class="csBigIcon" showWhen="android,windows"></ion-icon>
      </button>
    </ion-buttons>
    <ion-title>
      Select Anyone
    </ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>
  <ion-toolbar color="primary" no-border-top>
    <ion-searchbar [(ngModel)]="searchQuery" (ionInput)="getItems($event)" placeholder="Search">
    </ion-searchbar>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>
<ion-content class="csGrayBackground">
  <ion-list>
    <ion-item-sliding *ngFor="let detail of details; let i = index;" class="new-list" #slidingItem>
      <a ion-item ion-item detail-push detail-none href="#" (click)="openViewModal(detail, i)">
        <h2>{{detail.Fname}} {{detail.Lname}}</h2>
      </a>
      <ion-item-options side="left">
        <button ion-button color="primary" (click)="buttonClick(detail)">
          <ion-icon name="clipboard"></ion-icon>
          Edit
        </button>
        <button ion-button color="danger" (click)="deleteEmpDetail(detail)">
          <ion-icon name="trash"></ion-icon>
          Delete
        </button>
      </ion-item-options>
    </ion-item-sliding>
  </ion-list>
</ion-content>
```

Comment: The search bar issue is solved and I can see why. But my sliding options are still not working.
Thank you so much for your help. I guess I'll figure out a way.

Comment: Please add some context to as why your solution works. Now we have to search and try and look for what you have changed. Please point out what you have changed, it will improve your answer a lot :)